# Cross Domain Cookies - Avoid Ad Block?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies

Facebook has a marketing tool known as the pixel which allows websites to marketers to define specific user events to Facebook to build custom audiences.

How this works:

1. User visits mypage.com
2. `mypage.com` loads the facebook pixel code and fires an ajax call to `https://www.facebook.com/tr`
3. because the user is logged into facebook, the request mentioned in #2 will be able to send the cookies that exist in the browser for `.facebook.com` when the ajax call fires.

However, I realized that if you have ad blockers, the facebook pixel doesn't work because the ad blocker doesn't allow cross domain connection.

I am interested to build a proxy service hosted on `mypage.com` so that the facebook pixel doesn't have to make a call to `https://www.facebook.com/tr`. Instead it will fire to `mypage.com/tr` which then proxies the call to `https://www.facebook.com/tr`. (I've built this already).

Now the question is, how can I access the cookies on my users' browers for .facebook.com?

If doing so it not feasible, are there other ways I can get around the problem of getting the cookie to work even when there is an ad blocker?

Comment: That is not possible of course

Comment: The blocker would not be doing its job, if you could just bypass it willy-nilly. And the user installed it, because they do not want that kind of tracking. How about just respecting that?

Answer (score 3):

> Now the question is, how can I access the cookies on my users' browers for .facebook.com?

You can't.

Just think, if you could, you could hijack their session cookies and whatnot. That would be a security disaster.

> If doing so it not feasible, are there other ways I can get around the problem of getting the cookie to work even when there is an ad blocker?

Nope, see above point about security.

If it makes you feel any better, your proxy system would just get added to the ad block filters anyway.